# Website for a directory listing of taxi services?

Tags: web-development, template

I'm trying to build a self-listing website around a taxi service domain name that I have.

I am looking for a simple script / program that allows users to register, put up details about their taxi service - where they operate, what their contact numbers are, etc.

I'm not looking for a sophisticated program - bares bones is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give these a shot:

- [PHPDirectory](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sbd-directory-software)
- [dweb](http://freshmeat.net/projects/dweb)
- [direx](http://freshmeat.net/projects/direx)
- [PHP Weby](http://freshmeat.net/projects/phpdirectoryscript)
- [GippleDee](http://freshmeat.net/projects/gpld) (the open source fork of the phpLD app that John Conde mentioned)

—from: http://freshmeat.net/search?page=1&q=directory&submit=Search&with=12&without=

Though, to be honest, I'm not too impressed by any of the commercial or open source options. You might want to try to adapt a more general purpose wiki (niche software generally has fewer developers & software publishers, and thus lower software quality) as Evgeny suggests, or otherwise look for a Drupal/Joomla module or something.

Answer (score 1):

You might find a wiki useful, there are plenty of those available and most are simple enough. See [wikimatrix.org](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) for a comparison of wikis to find the ones with proper permissions support.

Or you can use a blog, like [wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org), that will allow people to leave comments with their details after registering.

Or you can hire a programmer for 2 hours of work and get the very basic thing you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Directory software would work well, too. It would allow you to break down down by location, too. [phpLD](http://www.phplinkdirectory.com/articlescript/index.php) would be a good one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Though, to be honest, I'm not too impressed by any of the commercial or open source options. You might want to try to adapt a more general purpose wiki (niche software generally has fewer developers & software publishers, and thus lower software quality) as Evgeny suggests, or otherwise look for a Drupal/Joomla module or something.